# How to blur real-time results so they can't be adjusted by browser dev tools

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page on a Laravel application that shows a list of sign-ups ordered by date created desc. The information displays an avatar thumbnail and then some other related fields.

For now, I would like to restrict viewing of that list by blurring it until certain criteria have been met by the user who has signed up. But I also want to show the user that the page exists - so it is kind of a teaser to encourage them to complete signup in that once they have done so they will be able to access the complete list.

This is easy to do using blur functionality in CSS but the issue is that can easily be bypassed using browser dev tools.

I am currently using a static image in place of real-time results but it is obvious to the user that their info is not included as their avatar is not showing (even though it is blurred it would still be slightly recognizable to them considering they would just have uploaded it).

I had considered generating the page and then screen scraping it (using something like `spatie/browsershot`) to create the static image but actually am not sure if that is the best option. Especially as this is only a temporary scenario as once we have enough signups we won't want to blur out the results page.

Any ideas on how to achieve the results I need? Or would screen scraping be the preferred option?

EDIT:

Just to be clear; I am not going the CSS route - that is why this question was posted. I am looking for server-side alternatives to that.

Comment: Why not use static images for users, except the current one?

Comment: If you want to blur images, without chance of user extracting unblurred, you need to do the blurring server side.

Comment: If you don't want the user to have some data, then don't send it to them at all. Anything you send to the browser is under the full control of the user, not you, no matter how much javascript or CSS you write around it. If the user isn't logged in, send dummy data and blur _that_.